# try except and programming etiquette

Tags: python

I'm making a GUI and I'm finding myself to be using a lot of `try` `except` statements.  My question is, should I be redesigning my program to use less `try` `except` statements or is `try` `except` a good practice to be using in python programs?  I like them because they're informative and make debugging, for me, easier.  Just wondering what real developers think about it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "good practice"? If you need to catch an exception, you need to catch an exception. What's the alternative?

Comment: If it helps you better understand your own programs and makes your life easier, do it. You're not on a mission to write the best code on Earth, right?

Comment: @jterrace: It is really more related to how Python is meant to work than you think. [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) is the common approach, but I believe it can be spoiled too. _Diaper antipattern_ being one of the examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of Python's idioms is: [It's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission.](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Python Glossary, have a look at EAFP).

So it's perfectly acceptable to structure program flow with exception handling (and reasonably fast too, compared to other languages). It fits Python's dynamic nature nicely imho.

Answer (score 4):

One large consideration when deciding whether to catch an exception is what legitimate errors you could be hiding.

For example, consider this code:

```
try:
    name = person['name']
except KeyError:
    name = '<none provided>'
```

This is reasonable if `person` is known to be a `dict`… But if `person` can possibly be something more complex, for example:

```
class Person(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return do_something(key)
```

You run the risk of accidentally catching an exception which was the result of a legitimate bug (for example, a bug in `do_something`).

And I feel the need to mention: you should [never, ever (except under a couple of very specific circumstances) use a "naked" `except:`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--).

My personal preference is to avoid catching exceptions when ever possible (for example, using `name = person.get('name', '<none provided>')`), both because I find it cleaner and I dislike the look of try/catch blocks.

Comment: +1 I definitely agree with using `get(name, default)` instead of the `try`/`except` alternative

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give a general answer on whether you should use less exception handling... you can definitely do too much and too little. It's almost certainly wrong to be catching every possible exception and also almost certainly wrong to be doing no exception handling.

Here are some things to think about:

- It's usually a good idea to catch the exception if you can programmatically do something about the error condition. E.g. your code is trying to make a web request and if it fails, you want to retry. In that situation you want to catch the exception and then do the retry.
- Think carefully about *where* to catch an exception. In some low-level function, can you reasonably do something about the error? E.g. let's say you have a function that writes out a file and it fails with a permissions error. Probably not much you can do about it there but maybe at a higher level you can catch the exception and display a message to the user instructing them to try to save the file somewhere else.
- It almost never makes sense to catch "fatal" types of errors e.g. out of memory, stack overflow etc. At least not low down in your code - it might make sense to have a top-level handler that tries to gracefully exit.
- Don't "swallow" exceptions that really should bubble up i.e. don't have an except clause that doesn't re-raise the exception if your calling function should really see it. This can hide serious bugs.

For more, do a Google search for "exception handling guidelines". Many of the results you see will be for other languages/environments, but the concepts apply just as well.